# Mapping a dictionary to pandas series using lambda

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda, mapping, series

I am trying to map a dictionary against a pandas series using lambda. Instead of mapping the values against the series 'Food', it's returning the whole dictionary against it. I know I need to amend the lambda function but don't know how.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'food': ['bacon', 'pulled pork', 'bacon','Pastrami', 'corned beef', 'Bacon','pastrami', 'honey ham', 'nova lox'], 'ounces': [4, 3, 12, 6, 7.5, 8, 3, 5, 6]})

food_to_animal = {'bacon': 'pig',  'pulled pork': 'pig',  'pastrami': 'cow',  'corned beef': 'cow',  'honey ham': 'pig',  'nova lox': 'salmon'} 

data['food'].map(lambda x: food_to_animal)
```

​
OUTPUT:
​

```
0    {'bacon': 'pig', 'pulled pork': 'pig', 'pastra...
1    {'bacon': 'pig', 'pulled pork': 'pig', 'pastra...
2    {'bacon': 'pig', 'pulled pork': 'pig', 'pastra...
3    {'bacon': 'pig', 'pulled pork': 'pig', 'pastra...
4    {'bacon': 'pig', 'pulled pork': 'pig', 'pastra...
5    {'bacon': 'pig', 'pulled pork': 'pig', 'pastra...
6    {'bacon': 'pig', 'pulled pork': 'pig', 'pastra...
7    {'bacon': 'pig', 'pulled pork': 'pig', 'pastra...
8    {'bacon': 'pig', 'pulled pork': 'pig', 'pastra...
Name: food, dtype: object
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
0     pig
1     pig
2     pig
3     cow
4     cow
5     pig
6     cow
7     pig
8     salmon
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try make the `df.food` value `lower case` and `map` dictionary

```
 data['food'].str.lower().map(food_to_animal)
```

and to a column

```
data['x']= data['food'].str.lower().map(food_to_animal)

0       pig
1       pig
2       pig
3       cow
4       cow
5       pig
6       cow
7       pig
8    salmon
Name: food, dtype: object
```

Comment: Yes. But I need to learn how lambda works and for me it's important to understand the question I asked.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, you do not need the lambda. Panda's `replace` knows how to work with dictionaries. Just make sure that the keys are in the right case:

```
data.food.str.lower().replace(food_to_animal)
```

P.S.: `map` + `lambda` work about 2x faster than `replace` or `map` + dictionary.

Comment: Yes. But I need to learn how lambda works and for me it's important to understand the question I asked.

Answer (score 1):

**That's the exact solution to map the numbers into day name. 'timeStamp' is the column that contain the date like   **2015-12-10 17:40:00****

```
    df['Day of Week']=df['timeStamp'].apply(lambda time: time.dayofweek)
    dmap = {0:'Mon',1:'Tue',2:'Wed',3:'Thu',4:'Fri',5:'Sat',6:'Sun'}
    
    df['Day of Week'] = df['Day of Week'].map(dmap)
    df['Day of Week']
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you:

```
data['food'].map(lambda x: food_to_animal[x])
```

you will get a `KeyError` if you don't adjust `data.food` to `lowercase`

to prevent this error, you could use `defaultdict`